# Joining tables and returning the correct aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm using Sean Lahman's Baseball database to aggregate runs, hits and 'at bats', wins & losses by team between the year 2010 and 2015. I want to join Teams and Batting table and use the group by function on teamID to return total runs, hits, at bats as well as wins and losses by team from the Teams table.

For instance, from the teams table I want to return wins and losses year wise

```
team ID Name             Wins  Losses Year
ARI Arizona Diamondbacks    65  97  2010
ARI Arizona Diamondbacks    94  68  2011
```

And from the Batting Table this is the output I want

```
year   teamID Runs Hits  At Bats
2012    ARI 734   1416  5462
2015    ARI 720  1494   5649
```

I tried the following query but it is returning inflated values for wins and losses columns:

```
select b.yearID, b.teamID, SUM(b.R) as Runs, SUM(b.H) as Hits, SUM(b.AB) as At_Bats, 
t.name as Team_Name, SUM(t.W) as Wins, SUM(t.L) as Losses
from Batting b, Teams t
where b.teamID = t.teamID and b.yearID=t.yearID and b.yearID between '2010' and '2015'
group by b.teamID, b.yearID, t.name, t.W, t.L
order by b.teamID
```

Documentation can be found here for the database http://www.seanlahman.com/files/database/readme2017.txt

Comment: select b.yearID, b.teamID,
       SUM(b.R) as Runs,
       SUM(b.H) as Hits,
       SUM(b.AB) as At_Bats, 
       t.name as Team_Name, 
       SUM(t.W) as Wins,
       SUM(t.L) as Losses
  from Batting b
  INNER JOIN Teams t ON t.teamID = b.teamID AND b.yearID = t.yearID 
where b.yearID between '2010' and '2015'
  AND t.teamID = 'ARI' 
group by b.teamID, b.yearID 
order by b.teamID

Comment: the SQL I shared could be used as a starring point to give you a slightly different concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I can't find that in the documentation, I guess that each combination of teamID and yearID uniquely identifies a record in the Teams table. When summing up wins and losses, you multiply them by the number of related players. So just don't build sums on t.W and t.L:

```
select b.yearID, b.teamID, SUM(b.R) as Runs, SUM(b.H) as Hits, SUM(b.AB) as At_Bats, 
t.name as Team_Name, t.W as Wins, t.L as Losses
from Batting b, Teams t
where b.teamID = t.teamID and b.yearID=t.yearID and b.yearID between '2010' and '2015'
group by b.teamID, b.yearID, t.name, t.W, t.L
order by b.teamID
```

Comment: @KAT please accept the answer so your question goes out of the unanswered questions.